# How to expose associated record using grape entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, grape-api, grape-entity

Hi I have a model `Event` and this event has one `Setting`. e.g

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :setting
end

class Setting < ActieRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

My event entity looks some thing like

```
module Entities
    class EventEntity < Grape::Entity
      expose :id
      expose :name, documentation: { type: String, desc: "Event name", required: true}
      expose :setting, using: Entities::EventSettingEntity
    end
end
```

My `EventSettingEntity` class looks something like

```
module Entities
  class EventSettingEntity < Grape::Entity
    expose :id, :event_id
    expose :type, documentation: { type: String, desc: "Type" }
  end
end
```

My Api is like

```
desc 'Create an event.' ,{
        params: Entities::EventEntity.documentation, type: :create
}
post 'create' do
  event = Event.create(params)
  present event, with: EventEntity
end
```

But the main problem is event creation form is not showing `setting` class `type` field. Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but your questions isn't clear enough. Where do you have a problem in your code? Is it related to the HTML form? Is it related to your API? Is this problem happening when you persist the model using ActiveRecord? Please, reformulate your question so I can help you out.

Comment: Yes it is related to html form, how do I show association fields in my form? Thanks